# Non-Exact solution to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Question:

$$ \text{Solve:}  \; \; (3xy+y^2)dx+(x^2+xy)dy=0$$

Solution Thus far:

$$ M = 3xy+y^2 \; \text{and} \; N= x^2+xy $$
$$ \frac{\partial{M(x,y)}}{\partial{y}} = 3x + 2y$$
$$ \frac{\partial{N(x,y)}}{\partial{x}} = 2x + y$$
$$ \implies \frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}} -\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} \neq 0 $$
Hence this is not an exact equation therefore we must apply an integrating factor such that:
$$ \mu(x,y)M (x,y)+ \mu(x,y) N (x,y) = 0 $$ which is an exact equation
, meaning this is equivalent so solving the equation:
$$ \frac{\partial{\mu(x,y)M(x,y)}}{\partial{y}} = \frac{\partial{\mu(x,y)N(x,y)}}{\partial{x}} $$
Now rearrange this into a more computationally friendly form:
$$ (-N(x,y)) \frac{\partial{\mu}}{\partial{x}} + M(x,y)\frac{\partial{\mu}}{\partial{y}} =  \bigg{(} \frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}} -\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} \bigg{)} \mu $$
$ \text{define:} \; \mu = \text{integrating factor} $

Where I'm stuck:

$ \mu (x,y) = \mu(x) $ did not work
$ \mu (x,y) = \mu(y) $ did not work
$ \mu (x,y) = \mu(x+y) $ nearly worked but didn't

This guess and testing of an integrating factor is too difficult for me. How does one gain the intuition to find it. Or am I using the wrong technique entirely? Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Usually finding an integrating factor to make an ODE exact is a hard task. There are the usual two cases of course, but after that, it's really educated guessing. The exercises I've seen for this type of problem usually tell you what integrating factor to use.

Comment: The integrating facor depends only on $x$ Try it's simple

Comment: You are right, computational errors in taking partial derivatives ughhh. Happens I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given

$$(3xy+y^2)dx+(x^2+xy)dy=0$$

Rearrange the differential equation to

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{3xy+y^2}{x^2+xy}$$

then let $$y=vx,\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=v + x\frac{dv}{dx}$$

The differential equation becomes

$$v + x\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{3x^2v+v^2x^2}{x^2+x^2v}$$
$$v + x\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{3v+v^2}{1+v}$$
$$x\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{4v+2v^2}{1+v}$$
$$\frac{1+v}{4v+2v^2}\,dv=-\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$
$$\frac{2+2v}{2v+v^2}\,dv=-\frac{4}{x}\,dx$$

Integrate both sides.

In general, a common strategy is to rewrite the first order differential equation as a [homogeneous equation](https://www.math24.net/homogeneous-equations/) of the form

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$$

from which a common substitution is $y=vx$. The first order equation can then be solved as a separable equation after you substitute the values of $y$ and $dy$ and then simplify.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Solve:}  \; \; (3xy+y^2)dx+(x^2+xy)dy=0$$

Multiply by Integrating Factor that depends only on $x$:
$$(3xy+y^2)\mu(x)dx+(x^2+xy)\mu(x)dy=0$$
$$Mdx+Ndy=0$$
$$M_y=\mu(x)(3x+2y), \; $$
$$N_x=\mu '(x) (x^2+xy)+\mu(x) (2x+y)$$
For exactness we need that:
$$\mu(x)(3x+2y)=\mu '(x) (x^2+xy)+\mu(x) (2x+y)$$
$$ \implies \frac {\mu '(x)}{ \mu (x)}=\frac {1}{x}$$
$$\ln |\mu (x )|=\ln x  \implies \mu(x)=x$$

Multiply by Integrating Factor that depends only on $x$ and $\mu(x)=x$ :
$$(3x^2y+y^2x)dx+(x^3+x^2y)dy=0$$
$$Mdx+Ndy=0$$
$$M_y=3x^2+2yx,\,\, N_x=3x^2+2xy$$
It's exact...Maybe you made a mistake somewhere ? Do the calculations again for the integrating factor.

---

**Another way:**

$$\text{Solve:}  \; \; (3xy+y^2)dx+(x^2+xy)dy=0$$
$$(3x^2y+y^2x)dx+(x^3+x^2y)dy=0$$
Rearrange terms:
$$(3x^2ydx+x^3dy)+(y^2xdx+x^2ydy)=0$$
$$d(x^3y)+\frac 12(2y^2xdx+2x^2ydy)=0$$
Now, it's exact:
$$d(x^3y)+\frac 12d(xy)^2=0$$
Integrate:
$$\boxed {2x^3y+(xy)^2=K}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can try converting into a homogeneous equation. Write it in the form:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{y(3+\frac{y}{x})}{x(1+\frac{y}{x})} $$

Then use the substitution $v=\frac{y}{x}$. Can you take it from here?

Edit: There is a nice justification for this kind of substitution. It comes from the fact that the functions $M(x,y)=3xy+y^2$ and $N(x,y)=x^2+xy$ are homogeneous polynomials of degree $2$.

A polynomial $P$ of $n$ variables is said to be homogeneous of degree $d$ whenever $P(\lambda x_1,\lambda x_2,\dots,\lambda x_n) = \lambda^d P(x_1, x_2,\dots,x_n)$. Here, we have that $d=2$ and $n=2$ for $M$ and $N$.

The idea behind the substitution is to then reduce the number of variables. Note that you can always express the equation as:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{3xy+y^2}{x^2+xy} =F(x,y)$$

To reduce the number of variables of $F$ from $2$ to $1$, you use the fact that $M$ and $N$ are homogeneous and write:

$$ F(\lambda x,\lambda y) = -\frac{M(\lambda x,\lambda y)}{N(\lambda x,\lambda y)} = -\frac{M(x,y)}{N(x,y)} $$

Letting $\lambda = \frac{1}{x} $ accomplishes just this. So we'd have instead:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= F(1, \frac{y}{x}) = f(\frac{y}{x})=-\frac{3(\frac{y}{x})+(\frac{y}{x})^2}{1+\frac{y}{x}}$$

You can naively think about it as just replacing $x$ by $1$ and $y$ by $\frac{y}{x}$. The function $f$ is only dependent on one variable, put this new variable as $v = \frac{y}{x}$. Then you can proceed as you would normally.

Comment: As crazy as this sounds, this topic was introduced to me quite rigorously. Where when the ODE is satisfied, $du(x,y) = 0 \implies u(x,y) = C $ ie.) level set curve. So I had no idea such a technique existed where u could just do this easy trick. I feel so oblivious

Comment: I mean the focus of my ODE/calculus courses hasn’t really ever been very computational. So i sometimes feel very silly not knowing these tricks that make a difficult problem suddenly manageable.

Comment: @Rick no worries! Sometimes these substitutions are motivated by theory, sometimes they're more counterintuitive. In this case, there is some basis for it in what's known as homogeneous polynomials.

Comment: If you get to study algebraic curves, you will get to see a process called "homogenization" of a polynomial. This is related to these ideas in a more fundamental/theoretical level.